# SimpleDateFormat giving error for the same input for Time

Tags: java, android

I am really not able to understand why SimpleDateFormat is throwing error for the very similar inputs.

I am passing two values : **"05:20 AM"** & **"05:50 AM"**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class FormateDate  {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String date_s = "05:20 AM";
        //String date_s = "05:50 AM";
        String date_ss;

        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
       Date date = dt.parse(date_s);
        

        // *** same for the format String below
        
        System.out.println(dt.format(date));
    }
}
```

The first value throws error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "05:20 AM"
```

and the second value one prints output : 05:50 AM

**NOTE**: Let me be clear that it is not a typo error or copy/paste error. Both strings are coming from my backend in API and I was not able to figure out why the first one throws an error.

Comment: Do not delete this Question. This use of non-breaking space character is an important issue, as some localizations recently adopted the use of that character to keep the AM/PM next to time-of-day. I don’t recall details at the moment, but will soon try to find my sources again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got non-ASCII unicode symbols in your input strings. Fortunately, you copy/pasted and, and pasted those too.

`date_s` is the following sequence of characters:

- 0
- 5
- :
- 2
- 0

so far, so  good.

- 0xE280AF
- A
- M

What the heck are those 3 bytes before `AM`?

It's the UTF-8 encoding of the unicode symbol U+202F: [The narrow no-break space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202F).

Probably a browser where someone used `&nbsp;` instead of a space.

SimpleDateFormat is obsolete. Do not use it; use the stuff in `java.time` instead (DateTimeFormatter). But, if you insist on using SDF, try:

```
String date_s = "05:20 AM".replaceAll("\\p{Z}", " ");
```

That weird incantation is using regexp to say: "replace all characters that fit in the unicode Z set (which is all whitespace codepoint) with an actual space". That actual space is something SDF can handle; those fancy unicode spaces aren't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels answers to questions that are caused by typos are inherently unuseful, as they hinder the effort to clean up the question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I usually agree with you on this except when I don't. Usually a typo question is a low quality affair that often attracts low quality answers, but occasionally you see a pretty decent answer that shows decent sleuthing and excellent exposition, sometimes enough to raise the utility of the question. This may be such a case. But as always, I encourage you to vote as you see fit, and I'll do the same.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is no mere typo. The non-breaking space has recently been **adopted for some localizations** of date-time formats. This choice makes sense as the AM/PM should indeed be kept with the time-of-day, not separated by a line break. I just read this week about this new adoption, likely related to the Unicode CLDR, but I cannot recall exactly. I’ll investigate tomorrow.

Comment: Let me be clear to you guys thats its not type error. Both the data is coming from my backend and I was unable to figure the difference in both the data. So I do want to try this answer

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It Worked.
I spent hours and hours figuring out the difference between those two strings.